# What is the use of a "Group Input" directly in the Node tree of the material?

Tags: materials, node-editor, shader-nodes

What is the use of a "Group Input" directly in the Node tree of the material? Note, not within a nodes group

It can be easily added to the material nodes tree, but I don't understand its usefulness.

Is there any particular function? If so, which one?

[image]

Note:

I know what a group inputs node in the node group is for.
So my question is specific what it is for in a node_tree of the material.

If anyone is 100% sure that the "Group input" node in the material node_tree is useless, please explain why

Comment: I don't think that it is useful out of the node group itself, it is useful in the node group, if you want to create another set of inputs or outputs

Comment: +1 moonboots ... probably they should not be accessible from GUI out of node group or be able to copy-paste out of group at all.

Comment: I describe your "within a nodes group" use below.  Unlike Geometry nodes -- where Group Inputs and Group Outputs appear in the GeometryNodes modifier, there is no such access to defined variables in the top level of a material node.  In some ways the shader editor doesn't know that you're *inside* a group or at a top level.

Comment: Semantically node group trees and top level node trees are the same. The information is stored in its user's properties, but any node tree can have an indefinite number of users. I think there is no way to know the information "this node tree is top level" without first having to iterate over all nodes of all node trees of all materials in the scene to check if this particular node tree isn't used as a node group. So the answer would be : "none". But it's computationally expensive to check if this node should be available in the context of a node tree. My 2 cents

Comment: @Gorgious I just tested in Python: mat.node_tree.inputs this returns the inputs without having to iterate the nodes in the node_tree, also python recognizes it as a node_tree (Just like in the case of a Node Group)

Comment: Yes, but this is a member of all node trees constructs so having an empty `inputs` collections doesn't necessarily mean that a node tree is top level, only that it has no inputs.

Comment: @Gorgious Ok, we agree on this. It would also be nice to have some input on the material, I was looking for that too. But it seems like you can't have access to this input at the top level

Comment: In geometry nodes, you can use a top level node tree as a custom group within a node tree. Perhaps Blender devs plan to change material nodes to work in the same way...

Comment: Even better is the fact that if you use both GroupInput and GroupOutput (with the surace, volume and displacement outputs), you can reuse complete materials as a node in other materials!!

Comment: @Secrop I  can't reproduce it, testing on Blender 3.2. Is it a new feature in Blender 3.3? I think if you can show how to do it, it's worthy of an answer.

Comment: If you grab your whole material except the Material Output Node and put it in a group. You can expose input values to that material in the GroupInput, and reuse it in other materials. (In Previous versions of Blender you could even use the material's nodetree directly in a ShaderNodeGroup, but in the current build the parser has changed for worse and that doesn't work anymore)

Comment: What do you mean by the "previous versions, @Secrop ? 3.1 and earlier?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady idk exactly when this had changed but it was working around 09/2020 as you can see here: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/how-useful-could-be-a-material-input-node/15104/13?u=secrop

Comment: @Secrop so will you write the answer with using the input and output to direct the connections of input and output groups when creating a custom group? It seems like the only usage currently, and would be a shame for bounty being wasted.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady as it seems, noob-cat doesn't care for the correct answer. It's a lame, I know.. such attitudes just make people not wanting to share anymore whatever knowledge they have.

Comment: @Secrop maybe OP hoped for a different answer. It is somewhat anticlimactic that those nodes can't be used in a better way.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is simply that there's a bug with the poll function for the GroupInput and the GroupOutput (perhaps because those are now being yielded by a generator).

As this is something that is not checked in the typical tests, and most developers aren't looking for these kind of defects, it's one of those little strange things that finds its way into the final release.

It's not a priority bug and probably nobody reported it, so no developer has picked it and solved it.

Comment: Meanwhile, a patch was commited and new versions of Blender should have this fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This is super-quirky, but if make a custom group out of a single node, inputs and outputs are automatically connected, but you can control the order of inputs using the *Group Input* node - for example, if you want the *Scale* and *Detail* of *Noise Texture* to be last:

[image]

Notice how the types of sockets don't matter for this.

Same for *Group Output*:

[image]

---

When you convert multiply nodes to a group, you can use *Group Input* and *Group Output* to make the input/output connections even before grouping, which is very helpful, even though you can't modify the types and names of *Group Input*/*Group Output* sockets:

[image]